# Syntax error al ejecutar

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo una calculadora con Python. He empezado hace poco ha aprender Python, por lo que no sé mucho del tema. 
Al ejecutar el código, me da

> "Syntax Error"

¿Cuál es la solución?
Me sigue dando el mismo error!
~
Aquí el código:

```
while True:

print('Opciones: ')
print ('Escribe "add" para sumar dos numeros')
print ('Escribe "subtract" para restar dos numeros')
print ('Escribe "multiply" para multiplicar dos numeros')
print ('Escribe "divide" para dividir dos numeros')
print ('Escribe "quit" para cerrar la calculadora')
user_input = input(": ")

if user_input == "quit":
 print ('Hasta la proxima')
break

elif user_input == "add":
 num1 = float(input("Escribe un numero: "))
 num2 = float(input("Escribe un numero: "))
 resultado = str(num1 + num2)
 print("La respuesta es " + resultado)

elif user_input == "subtract":
 num1 = float(input("Escribe un numero: "))
 num2 = float(input("Escribe un numero: "))
 resultado = str(num1 + num2)
 print("La respuesta es " + resultado)

elif user_input == "multiply":
 num1 = float(input("Escribe un numero: "))
 num2 = float(input("Escribe un numero: "))
 resultado = str(num1 + num2)
 print("La respuesta es " + resultado)

elif user_input == "divide":
 num1 = float(input("Escribe un numero: "))
 num2 = float(input("Escribe un numero: "))
 resultado = str(num1 + num2)
 print("La respuesta es " + resultado)

else:
 print("ERROR-Onbekende input")
```

Comment: ¿En que línea te da el error?

Comment: Ese es el problema jajajja, no me da en ninguna línea error.

Comment: A vale, realmente nunca he programado en Phyton pero igual eso podía ayudar al resto de usuarios a enfocar el problema.

Comment: Copié tu código tal como tal y lo ejecuté local en mi maquina, me tiro errores por las tildes y el `break` que tienes al terminar tu primer `if`, al remover las tildes y el `break` me funcionó correctamente, por favor revisa :)

Comment: Error te da seguro, con ese `break` ahí provocas que el `elif` no tenga inmediatamente antes de el un `if` , eso te tirará un error de sintaxis seguro. Quitalo y ya está, `break` se usa para salir de un ciclo, donde lo tienes no te sirve para nada (a no ser que tu código este dentro de un `while` por ejemplo, y en ese caso si tendría sentido pero el `break` ira dentro del `if`).

Comment: pero cómo puedo hacer que cuándo escriban "quit" se cierre la aplicación?

Comment: Es que al entrar en el `if` se imprime el mensaje y se termina la aplicación, no hace falta nada más. Los `elif` y el `else` ni siquiera se evaluan si se entra en el `if`, como no hay más código a ejecutar la aplicación **termina**. Otra cosa es que estes intentando que se puedan hacer **varias operaciones hasta que el usuario introduzca 'quit'**, en ese caso necesitas un `while True:`, meter dentro todo el código y usar el `break` pero dentro del `if`. ¿Es eso lo que intentas?

Comment: Si, gracias. Pero ahora cuándo le doy a Run, me sale todo en blanco. Por qué es eso?

Comment: Voy a crear una respuesta a ver si nos aclaramos antes.

Comment: He editado el código, pero aun así me sigue dando Syntax error. El código editado está arriba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según leo en los comentarios "Ese es el problema jajajja, no me da en ninguna línea error. – JuanVan12" cuando ejecutas el programa en un entorno de desarrollo por lo general te indicara donde esta el error. Yo utilizo Spyder y al ejecutar el programa me indica lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me dice que el error es en la linea 20, por lo general el error es mas arriba de esa linea osea debemos fijarnos en la linea 19,18... etc.

Se puede observar el signo de error que nos marca en la linea 20. Pero el error se encuentra en la 18 ya que el break no es necesario para este caso ya que no se esta utilizando por ejemplo un ciclo while.

Al eliminar el break, se elimina el warning y por ende el error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si ahora ejecutas el programa corre sin problemas. 
Saludos, espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 2):

Realmente ya te se ha contestado adecuadamente, pero dado que sigues con problemas (ver comentarios) voy a poner dos ejemplos de código funcionando. Si sigue sin andar bién ya no es problema del código:

Tal y como tienes el código, como ya te han comentado, solo tienes que eliminar el `break` ya que no tiene sentido usarlo de esta forma, sino para romper un ciclo. En este caso ocasiona que el `elif` no tenga inmediatamente antes de el un `if` y se produce un error de sintaxis. El código quedaría así:

```
print('Opciones: ')
print ('Escribe "add" para sumar dos números')
print ('Escribe "subtract" para restar dos números')
print ('Escribe "multiply" para multiplicar dos números')
print ('Escribe "divide" para dividir dos números')
print ('Escribe "quit" para cerrar la calculadora')
user_input = input(": ")

if user_input == "quit":
    print ('Hasta la próxima!')

elif user_input == "add":
    num1 = float(input("Escribe un número: "))
    num2 = float(input("Escribe un número: "))
    resultado = str(num1 + num2)
    print("La respuesta es " + resultado)

elif user_input == "subtract":
    num1 = float(input("Escribe un número: "))
    num2 = float(input("Escribe un número: "))
    resultado = str(num1 - num2)
    print("La respuesta es " + resultado)

elif user_input == "multiply":
    num1 = float(input("Escribe un número: "))
    num2 = float(input("Escribe un número: "))
    resultado = str(num1 * num2)
    print("La respuesta es " + resultado)

elif user_input == "divide":
    num1 = float(input("Escribe un número: "))
    num2 = float(input("Escribe un número: "))
    resultado = str(num1 / num2)
    print("La respuesta es " + resultado)
```

Si deseas que el programa puede hacer más de una operación por ejecucion, es decir puedes estar haciendo operaciones hasta que se introduzca 'quit' se usaria un ciclo infinito y en este caso si necesitarias el `break` para terminar la ejecución:

```
while True:
    print('Opciones: ')
    print ('Escribe "add" para sumar dos números')
    print ('Escribe "subtract" para restar dos números')
    print ('Escribe "multiply" para multiplicar dos números')
    print ('Escribe "divide" para dividir dos números')
    print ('Escribe "quit" para cerrar la calculadora')
    user_input = input(": ")

    if user_input == "quit":
        print ('Hasta la próxima!')
        break

    elif user_input == "add":
        num1 = float(input("Escribe un número: "))
        num2 = float(input("Escribe un número: "))
        resultado = str(num1 + num2)
        print("La respuesta es " + resultado)

    elif user_input == "subtract":
        num1 = float(input("Escribe un número: "))
        num2 = float(input("Escribe un número: "))
        resultado = str(num1 - num2)
        print("La respuesta es " + resultado)

    elif user_input == "multiply":
        num1 = float(input("Escribe un número: "))
        num2 = float(input("Escribe un número: "))
        resultado = str(num1 * num2)
        print("La respuesta es " + resultado)

    elif user_input == "divide":
        num1 = float(input("Escribe un número: "))
        num2 = float(input("Escribe un número: "))
        resultado = str(num1 / num2)
        print("La respuesta es " + resultado)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema está en esta línea de código al terminar el `if`:

```
if user_input == "quit":
    print ('Hasta la próxima!')
break // Aquí el break no es necesario ya que esto no es un condicional tipo switch, remueve este break y funcionará correctamente
```

También el uso de caracteres con tildes puede generarte problemas.